# Need help converting a Int64 Math Equation into a BigInteger Equivalent

Tags: c#, .net-core, biginteger

I have the following code:

```
   var price = (jObject["market_data"]["current_price"]["usd"].Value<double>());
   return Convert.ToInt64(1 / price * Math.Pow(10, 18));
```

if given the price 0.20150000 the result will be roughly 4951781438163283968

which works fine however if the price falls to $0.10 or lower the Int64 method will have an overflow issue as the number will become too large to hold in the Int64 object.

I have been trying to change this with BigInteger methods but I am not having much luck. So far I have tried:

```
BigInteger remainder = new BigInteger();
BigInteger price = BigInteger.Parse("201500000000000000");
BigInteger dividend = BigInteger.Parse("1000000000000000000");

var d = BigInteger.DivRem(dividend, price, out remainder);

d = {4}
remainder = {192000000000000000}
```

the results don't seem to add up the way I thought. I've never worked with BigInteger math before so need a little help here.

Comment: A better question might be what you're going to use this mind-bogglingly huge number for later, if this involves prices. If this is just one intermediate step in a bigger calculation there may be a way to (re)write it that neither loses precision nor involves dragging in bignums.

Comment: doesn't really matter what I'm doing with it, the point is I need it. I am asking a question can the above be done using BigInteger math?

Comment: I'm getting correct answer with a remainder of 194 (not 192).  I'm using the library System.Numerics.  Basically 1000 - 806 = 194.

Comment: @Dritzz "doesn't really matter what I'm doing with it, the point is I need it" This is always the case when somebody is having an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I also get a remainder of 194.

Answer (score 0):

If your result is possitive, you can try to use ulong/UInt64:

```
var price = 0.1d;
ulong res = Convert.ToUInt64(1 / price * Math.Pow(10, 18));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the explicit conversion, so just do:

```cs
return (BigInteger)(1 / price * Math.Pow(10, 18));
```